# Is it possible to change the UI of the app completely?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

after publishing apps to the play store, is there any downside if we completely change the UI of the app? or even the functionality of the app in the next updates.
for example, If my app is a music player app in the first update, what happens if I make it as a game in the second update? seems funny. but I would like to know this.
What really happens if we change the UI and behaviour of our released application to **play store**? is there any problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and [the Help Center page regarding appropriate topics for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can change the UI and/or behaviour without any issues but make sure your app does not violates any policy.

They will review your app update before publishing it to Google Play Store. So no need to worry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. tell me how I can Edit my question and why my Question is closed?